# Autonomous ODE, determine the limit given an initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the following autonomous ordinary differential equation, determine the equilibrium points, classify the equilibria as stable or unstable, and find $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}x(t)$ under the initial condition $x(0)=2$

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = (x-1)(x-2)x(x+1)(x+2)$$

Here is my work:

The equilibrium points are $x=2,1,0,-1,-2$
and $x=-2,0,2$ are unstable, $x= -1,1$ are stable.

What I don't understand is the presence of the initial condition $x(0) =2$. How will the initial condition effect the $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}x(t)$ ?

Edit: So if the initial condition is $x(0) =2 $ then $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}x(t) = 2$  ??

Comment: What's the problem? You solve the equation with initial conditions and find that $x(t)=2$.

Comment: It will determine to which stable equilibrium you will evolve.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy,I do not understand your statement "you solve the equation with initial conditions and find that $x(t) =2$. Can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: @Raskolnikov,the stable equilibria are $x=1,-1$. Does that mean $x(t)$ approaches 1 as $t$ approches $\infty$?

Comment: If $x(0)=2$, then $dx/dt$ is $0$ when $x=0$, and the function isn't changing.  Thereafter, there's nothing to change its value, so it's constant.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, I am sorry but I just do not understand. What do you mean by "if $x(0) =2$ then $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = 0 $ when $x=0$"? What if $x(0) = -2$?

Comment: Plug the number $-2$ into the right side of the differential equation and get $0$.  That way you check by substitution that $x(t)=-2$ for all values of $t$ is a solution to the differential equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You consider a Cauchy problem,

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = (x-1)(x-2)x(x+1)(x+2),\quad x(0)=2.$$

By applying [Picard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) we deduce that there exists a unique solution on some interval $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$. On the other hand, the right hand side is zero for $x=2$, so we can deduce that the solution "$x(t)$ is identically $2$" is a unique solution to our Cauchy problem. Therefore, $\lim x(t)=2$.